# Eigen Sparse valuePtr is displaing zeros, while leaving out valid values

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, eigen3

I don't understand the result I get when I try to iterate over `valuePtr` of a sparse matrix. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
  SparseMatrix<double> sm(4,5);

  std::vector<int> cols = {0,1,4,0,4,0,4};
  std::vector<int> rows = {0,0,0,2,2,3,3};
  std::vector<double> values = {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.3,0.7,0.9,0.2};

  for(int i=0; i < cols.size(); i++)
      sm.insert(rows[i], cols[i]) = values[i];

  std::cout << sm << std::endl;

  int nz = sm.nonZeros();
  std::cout << "non_zeros : " << nz << std::endl;

  for (auto it = sm.valuePtr(); it != sm.valuePtr() + nz; ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

Output:

0.2 0.4 0 0 0.6  // The values are in the matrix
0 0 0 0 0 
0.3 0 0 0 0.7 
0.9 0 0 0 0.2 

non_zeros : 7  
0.2            // but valuePtr() does not point to them
0.3            // I expected: 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2
0.9
0
0.4
0
0
```

I don't understand why I am getting zeros, what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html) for `SparseMatrix`:

> Unlike the compressed format, there might be extra space inbetween the
>   nonzeros of two successive columns (resp. rows) such that insertion of
>   new non-zero can be done with limited memory reallocation and copies.
>
> [...]
>
> A call to the function `makeCompressed()` turns the matrix into the standard compressed format compatible with many library.

[For example](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html):

> This storage scheme is better explained on an example. The following
>   matrix
>
> ```
> 0  3  0   0   0
> 22 0  0   0   17
> 7  5  0   1   0
> 0  0  0   0   0
> 0  0  14  0   8
> ```
>
> and one of its possible sparse, column major representation:
>
> ```
> Values:       22  7   _   3   5   14  _   _   1   _   17  8
> InnerIndices: 1   2   _   0   2   4   _   _   2   _   1   4
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The "_" indicates available free space to quickly insert new elements.

Since `valuePtr()` simply return a pointer to the `Values` array, you'll see the empty spaces (the zeroes that got printed) unless you make the matrix compressed.

Comment: Thank You. If I do `sm.makeCompressed()` everything is as I expected.